# Implementing protection circuitry for a single cell

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, lipo, battery-operated

I'm hoping to embed a protection circuit for a single 18650 in my device's circuit. No over-charge protection is needed since it won't allow charging - so only protection against over-discharge, reversed polarity and over-current/short-circuit.

I see that there're ICs like [BQ29312A](http://www.ti.com/product/bq29312A), but they're for 2-cell packs. Does anyone know of schematics that protect single 18650s with a working current 3-4A?

Thanks

Comment: Adding "UVLO" to your search phrase may help.

Comment: "No over-charge protection is needed since it won't allow charging" - then how does the battery get charged?

Comment: @BruceAbbott It can be charged using a separate home charger.

Comment: This may work if you find an appropriate MOSFET. http://danyk.cz/p_ochr_en.html

Comment: Seiko makes a complete range of such ICs. Typically you add external MOSFETs.

Answer (score 1):

There's the S-8261. Here's the circuit.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sii-ic.com](http://www.sii-ic.com/en/semicon/files/2013/05/p_783_2.gif))</sub>